# Binding DateTime property in ViewModel to three TextBoxes (day, month, year) in view

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a `PersonViewModel` with a `DateTime DateOfBirth` property in it. I want to create a View/Template for that following [this layout](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/48877/7838):

[image]

The problem is, I can't figure how to do the binding/validation:

- Should I use a DateTimeViewModel, that maps a single DateTime to three different bindable properties (Day, Month, Year)? If yes, what should be its lifecycle? I mean, I have the `Person.DateOfBirth` property, so what sould I bind to? And how would I perform validation when one property changes, and how would I update Person.DateOfBirth from that?
- Should I use a MultiValueConverter? If yes how should I declare it? I am used to MultiBinding many properties in VM to a single property in VW, but now I need to map a single property in ViewModel to many properties in View.
- How about BindingGroup? Is this a good use case for that?

Comment: I'd create a UserControl with a public DateTime(Offset?) DependencyProperty and handle all the jiggery pokery of translating one back to the other in the codebehind.  It'll probably be the cleanest way to do it.  Handling the error template might be a bit of a pain, but if you cheat you can get away without too much work (e.g., configurable min/max dates and change the visibility/color of Borders in response to edits).

Answer (score 0):

You can bind different properties of DateOfBirth to multiple TextBoxes i.e.

```
<TextBox x:key ="1" Text = "{Binding DateOfBirth.Day}" StringFormat=""../>
<TextBox x:key ="2" Text = "{Binding DateOfBirth.Month}" StringFormat=""../>
<TextBox x:key ="3" Text = "{Binding DateOfBirth.Year}" StringFormat=""../>
```

You can specify validation rules individually for these text boxes like IsValidDayRule, IsValidMonthRule etc. Also, you can do the validation in the viewmodel itself if you don't want to use ValidationRules. I think that is a cleaner approach.

You can also create a usercontrol for this as mentioned by Will in the comment. That would also be a better approach.